# how can i access to child in object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i want to access the child of Object!
for instance:
 we a have child(that name is a1) in k1 object.
how can i access it(my means a1 which in the k1)

```
var k1:keypad=new keypad();
k1.x=7.05;
k1.y=229.20;
add Child(k1);
this.k1.a1.addEventListener(Mouse Event.CLICK,ts);
function ts(event:Mouse Event):void{
 trace("OK");

};
```

thank you.

Comment: Please clarify what is or isn't currently happening.  Are you receiving an error? If so, edit your question to include the error message.  It would likely be helpful to show the code for you `keypad` class.  Most likely this line is throwing a compile time error:  `add Child(k1)` because of the space between add & child.

Comment: Dear create space between them because of site grammar form and i know this no any space between them.so when i write my code i have error:TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Dictation_fasl1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Dictation_fasl1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:310]

Comment: Ok,  please explain the `keypad` class.  How is that defined?  (a library object exported for actionscript?    A separate .as class file?)

Answer (score 0):

event has a property target. this one is the child which was clicked.

```
function ts(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(event.target);
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You are doing it wrong. You declare a local variable **k1**:

```
var k1:keypad
```

which is not a member of **this** object, you cannot access it

```
this.k1
```

So your code will probably work this way:

```
// Bad class name: lowercase.
var k1:keypad = new keypad;

k1.x = 7.05;
k1.y = 229.20;

// This is addChild() method, it is spelled without space.
addChild(k1);

// Then you access k1 just as you did above, without this.

// This will work if you designed your keypad with
// Adobe Flash IDE on default publish settings.
k1.a1.addEventListener(Mouse Event.CLICK, onA1);

// This will work too if a1's instance name is a1:
// k1.getChildByName("a1").addEventListener(Mouse Event.CLICK, onA1);

// Event handler. MouseEvent is a class name,
// it has no space inside.
function onA1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("OK");
}
// Normally you don't need ; after function body.
```

Comment: There is no issue with using `this.k1` in the same scope where the var is defined (which is the case here).    In that same block of code `k1` is indeed a member/property of `this`.    The OP's issue likely revolves around `add `... (which you've addressed)  or `k1` doesn't actually have a child named `a1` (or the `a1` var doesn't have a value set yet)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis It will be working as a frame script, yes, yet will not be working if the code is a function body. So it is generally better to declare and address things in the same way - unless the developer fully understands what he is doing and where all the data reside.

Comment: dear Organis!! thank you for your response! but unfortunately code dose not work! would you please help me and write it completely!!

Comment: @hosseini 1. **StackOverflow** is not a free code delivery service. My code is not (though might be) a solution - it is a (well commented) guideline that points out the mistakes and errors you've made. You are supposed to read, and learn, and test, and trace() everything to figure out where your code fails. 2. Even if I wanted to give you a complete solution, there are lots of things that could possibly alter the result, like if that a frame code, or function code, or class code, and how your whole project is set up.

Comment: OK dear!!! i understand. but our comment and your comment is not helper to another  visitor !! for this reason i wrote it  is not true so thank you for your patient